# Nested JMeter ForEach controller inside another ForEach controller

Tags: regex, foreach, controller, jmeter

This is what I have

```
TestPlan  
  Thread Group  
    HTTP Request1
      Regular Expression Extractor  - Return 10 Results - URLs  
    ForEach Controller - Using variable from extractor - **Successfully Loops through above results**  
      HTTP Request2
        Regular Expression Extractor  - Return 10 Results - URLs
      ForEach Controller-- **Run only one result** -- I want to run through all the above results from HTTP Request2
```

This is what I have
[image: TestPlan]

Comment: Show second regex,its ŕesponse and second foreach component

Comment: Second regex Reference Name : inputKitchenLevel2, Regex <a href="/nz/kitchen/${returnKitchenLevel1}/([^"]+)"> Template : $1$ Match No : -1
I am using Beanshell sampler to print the extracted values from regex which returns correct results

Comment: log.info("Enter Beanshell Sampler");
matches = vars.get("inputKitchenLevel2_matchNr");
log.info(matches);


 for (Integer i=1; i <= Integer.parseInt(matches); i++) 
{
 String url = vars.get("inputKitchenLevel2_"+i);

 log.info(i+"->" + url);

 }
Second foreach controller input variable: inputKitchenLevel2 output variable : returnKitchenLevel2 - i haven't given star or end index same as the first foreach controller
HTTP Request uses this ${returnKitchenLevel2}

Answer (score 1):

JMeter doesn't have any problems with the nested ForEach Controllers, given I have the following variables defined:

[image: JMeter User Defined Variables]

I'm able to iterate them in nested manner using 2 ForEach Controllers:

[image: JMeter Nested ForEach Controllers]

---

So my expectation is that either your Regular Expression Extractor configuration is incorrect (i.e. it returns only one match  - have you specified `-1` as "Match No"?) or ForEach Controller configuration is wrong.

- Inspect variables generated by the Regular Expression Extractor using [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination
- Check if nested ForEach Controllers work for your JMeter distribution, if not - [upgrade to latest available JMeter version](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) and make sure you don't have any plugins installed

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Dmitri I was using the variable in foreach controller as ${variable} instead it worked fine when I used just input variable as : variable

***Awesome***